# Why do objects have size?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

What is the reason objects, like coffee mugs, have size?

Comment: This seems like a list-based question, which makes it off-topic for this site.

Comment: @KyleKanos, where does it say that? Where should I ask it if not here?

Comment: List-based questions are disapproved of across *all* of the SE sites, not just here. Note also that asking for "ranking" is asking for an opinion as well, which is equally off-topic. I frankly don't care *where* you end up asking it, I'm simply saying that it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: You're referring to poll-type questions, where you request answers from everyone, and there is no right answer. There are definite reasons for the property of size, and each has a definite, objective, and measurable impact on that property. You might as well call "What causes clouds to form" a list question because it involves multiple factors, or "What are the fundamental interactions" because there are four of them.

Comment: No, I am **not** talking about polls, I said "list-based" for a reason. That reason is that you are asking for a *list* of "other factors" that you've missed. Then you want us to *arbitrarily* rank them. I'd say the clouds question would be too broad (it takes a textbook) and the fundamental interactions insufficient effort (because the answer is found on Wikipedia).

Comment: Just because you haphazardly asked for an explanation does not make this any less of a list based question. If you want to know how, say, the electromagnetic force gives an object its size, it'd probably be okay here. Asking for 'everything else" is just too broad.

Comment: I've changed the question so that it is no longer list-based, in the sense that I am no longer asking for a list of factors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing called energy, and it is conserved in the sense that if it leaves a region, you now have less of it in that region unless or until some more comes back into the region.  If you have some fundamental particles or composite objects they can have different energy based both on their state and how far apart they are from each other.  But if they ever arrange themselves in a way that has less energy and then they also give that excess energy away to something that isn't giving it back or at least not soon) such as radiating the energy into deep space, then they get stuck.  That's how hydrogen atoms $H$ get stuck to each other to form hydrogen molecules, $H_2$.  It's how carbon atoms form graphene, how organic molecules form, etcetera.

If the energy is lower when they are a certain distance apart, then they can get stuck that distance apart.  Like a spring that requires energy to compress it or the stretch it, if the energy is low enough it has no choice but to be at the distance that has the least energy.

Even the Pauli exclusion principle that people cite is just a special case of the same thing, that to be closer together given some states already, requires more energy so they stay at least a certain distance away.  Though it is a bit tricky because states can affect energy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know some but not all of the answer numerically. But the main answer is "electromagnetic repulsion" and "Pauli exclusion principle." The nucleus is very, very small compared to the entire atom, so nuclear effects are not much of it. Off the top of my head, I've seen the calculation for how much of the pressure in an ordinary metal (which is basically a gas of electrons) is due to Fermi pressure due to Pauli exclusion. It's about half, iirc.